# AD Sites - Replication Connections

Tags: active-directory

As I understand it, the KCC should automatically create To and From replication connections for your sites unless you disable this feature.

Looking through our AD Sites and Services, I can see that this is not the case for some of the DC's across our various sites.  Some DC's show that the connections were "" while others appear to be manual connections.  In addition, some DC's only have a singled auto generated connection while others have multiple.

The admin who set this up is not available so thought I'd do a bit of research on this.  I'd appreciate some thoughts on this as I brush up on my AD knowledge.

To clarify, is there a reason why the KCC is not auto generating the connections? I am concerned the sites are not setup correctly.

Thank You!

Comment: I didn't see an actual question in there?

Comment: Sorry, I added to the original post.  Basically I am wondering why the other connections aren't being added automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KCC creates replication connections based on your site topology, which you must define by creating sites and site links (and additionally by specifying site link costs); if f.e. you have 5 sites but site A is only linked to site C, then the only replication connections for DCs in site A will be created to/from DCs in site C, and nowhere else; the KCC will not create connections between a DC in site A and a DC in site B, D or E (well, unless all DCs in site C are down and site link bridging is enabled, but let's save this for another day).

It's impossible to tell whether the KCC is doing a good job or not without knowing how your topology is defined; the KCC usually does a pretty good job, so there are good chances there's something wrong with your site links if there are no connections where there are supposed to be some.

Comment: Our topology is based on using an MPLS network so we only have one site link which includes all of our sites.  I did not design this, but since we have fast reliable connections (100MB min) between all our sites, this is probably the reason. This should rule out DC replication issues based on sites?

Comment: The KCC only knows what you tell it about your site connections. If you only have one site link joining all your sites, it will simply connect your DCs in a random way, because all possible replication paths will look just the same.

Comment: So is it normal where I see one DC with automatically generated connections for 5 of the 7 DCs in our environment and one with only 1 of 7 DCs automatically generated connections?

Comment: Yes. It could depend on a lot of factors and on past events affecting the reachability of some of your DCs, but yes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  My main concern is that one of our DCs in a new site only shows one connection.  The connection is to a DC we will be demoting very soon.  I was concerned that this would cause the new site to loose replication connectivity with the rest of the domain.

Comment: No, if you properly demote the DC, the KCC will take care of replacing its connections with new ones. And even if you simply shut it down without demoting it, after a while the KCC will acknowledge it's not reachable and will reconfigure the replication topology to work around the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> To clarify, is there a reason why the KCC is not auto generating the connections? I am concerned the sites are not setup correctly.

This is one of the reasons why you should not manually modify AD replication topology beyond modifying site link costs unless you have a good reason to do so. (i.e., you have a disjointed network topology, i.e. not all domain controllers can talk to one another.)

But don't take my word for it:

[Microsoft says:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961787.aspx)

> The KCC is designed to produce a topology that provides low
>   replication latency, that adapts to failures, and that does not need
>   modification. Adding connections is not recommended because extra
>   connections gradually reduce the ability of the KCC to automatically
>   choose the best configurations. In addition, you create a situation
>   where you must continually evaluate whether the manual connections are
>   doing the best possible job of replicating changes.

And

> Create connections manually only if the connections that are automatically configured by the KCC do not connect specific domain controllers that you want to connect.

And

> • **As a last resort**, turn off automatic generation of intersite topology and create connections manually.

You can use `repadmin /siteoptions /site:Texas` to check the options on a given Active Directory site and see whether the ISTG (intersite topology generator) has been disabled or not. But even if it is not disabled, if you the administrator have created manual connection objects, the ISTG will not second-guess you or question your authority. It will assume you've manually modified the replication topology for a good reason.

As a general rule of thumb, (i.e. it may not apply everywhere all the time, but it applies to most cases,) if you have a fully-meshed network meaning all domain controllers in all sites can talk to one another, then I'd just delete all site links but one and put all the sites in that one site link. Alternatively if you'd rather have many site links even though you have a fully-meshed network, then make sure 'Bridge all site links' is checked to tell the ISTG that all sites can communicate with one another. If you have sites that cannot communicate with one another and instead replication must travel through an intercessory site (e.g., A -> B -> C) that's the time to un-bridge your site links.

Comment: I agree 100%.  Is there a way to confirm if intrAsite auto connections is disabled?

Comment: Intrasite replication happens differently than intersite - it happens via change notification. It is possible to make intersite replication occur via change notification as well as intrasite replication, but I don't know that it's even possible to turn intrasite replication off. That'd be essentially domain-breaking and it'd be seriously messed up.

Comment: That said, you can monitor intrasite replication with `repadmin /showreps /repsto` ... The repsto switch shows the domain controller's outbound change notification partners.

Comment: I ran the repadmin command suggested from a system the shows only one inbound connection in the Sites and Services GUI.  The output shows only one Inbound Neighbor.  I also got the following access was denied message at the end: DsReplicaGetInfo() failed with status 8453 (0x2105)
    Replication access was denied.
DsReplicaGetInfo() failed with status 8453 (0x2105)
    Replication access was denied.

Answer (score 0):

One scenario for manual connections is to have control over specifying a bridgehead server, perhaps due to firewall or network issues.  In the case of network issues, it's possible that the KCC may repeatedly create a lot of what appear to be redundant connections.  These can be spotted when the ms-DS-ReplicatesNCReason attribute contains an entry with the OSCILLATING_CONNECTION_TOPOLOGY bitflag.

When manually generated connections exist, the KCC uses them wherever possible.

If you cannot find a plausible explanation for the manual connection objects, and you want to use automatic connections, you can convert the existing manual connection into an automatic connection object.  This may preserve the manual connection object and eliminates the need to delete them during cleanup.  To do this, you can edit the 'options' attribute, and add the 1 to it (to specify it is automatically generated). The KCC will then either keep the connection or remove it and create a new connection.